# Grid configuration for running tests on any browser version and os

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Hello: i am running selenium 3.5.3 with appium 1.6.5 on the grid using java.

**Objective:**

To run tests in parallel on any available browser version and on any available os (i.e. windows, mac, linux, android, ios). For this example, i have used android and windows.

**Expected:**

When i run the TestRunner script (provided below) i expected all 5 tests to run as listed here in parallel:

1. Node-1: run 1 test on Firefox and 1 on Chrome
2. Node-2: run 1 test on Firefox and 1 on Chrome
3. Node-3: run 1 test on Chrome

**Result**

- Tests are initiated only on the Chrome Browser of Node-1 and Node-2
- No Tests are initiated on Node-3 (android) (note: it works if it set the driver class to AndroidDriver. But don't know to make it generic)
- No Tests are initiated for Firefox. (note: if it set the specifically set the browerName capability to firefox then it works)

**Please help.**

How can i make this work so that the tests run parallely on all browsers. Specifically, how to solve it for firefox and how to solve it for android-chrome.

**TestRunner script**

```
public class SeleniumGrid {
    @DataProvider (name = "DP", parallel=true)
    Object[][] DataGen(){
        String [][] arr = new String[][]{{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"},{"4"}, {"5"}};
        return arr;
    }

    @Test (dataProvider = "DP")
    void TestProvider(String value) throws MalformedURLException{
        System.out.println(value);      
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "firefox");
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
        //cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8");

        //**** AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"), cap);
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.get("http://www.testng.org");
        driver.quit();      
    }
}
```

**NODE1_windows config:**

```
{
    "capabilities": [
    {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 1
    },
    {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "version": "9"
    }   
    ],
    "maxSession": 2,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true
}
```

**NODE2_windows config:**

```
{
    "capabilities": [
    {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 1
    },
    {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "version": "9"
    }   
    ],
    "maxSession": 2,
    "port": 5556,
    "register": true
}
```

**NODE3_android config:**

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "platform" : "ANDROID",
            "browserName": "Chrome",
            "version": "5.1.1",
            "device" : "Appium",        
            "applicationName": "myNexus5",            
            "maxInstances": 1

        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4723,
        "maxSession": 1,
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "hubHost": "192.168.1.100",
        "role" : "node"
    }
}
```

**CLI initiators for HUB & NODES**

```
 - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -role hub
 - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="E:\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar    selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -role node -hub    http://localhost:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig node1_windows.json
 - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="E:\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig node2_windows.json
 - appium --nodeconfig node3_android.json -p 4723 -bp 4724 -U 06f0111111c86e3e
```